# Difference between "S" and "s" , "C" and "c", "Q" and "q" in svg?

Tags: html, svg, graphics, bezier

Can someone explain the difference between "S" and "s" , "C" and "c", "Q" and "q" command in svg d property , please help, and it would be sooo good if you could give a visual example .

Comment: The lowercase commands indicate that the following coordinates are given relative to the current location. These are all explained in the [documentation](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataCubicBezierCommands). Which part of it don't you understand?

Comment: This is pretty clearly explained in many places already, from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/d#path_commands) to the [SVG spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/paths.html#PathDataCubicBezierCommands) itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lowercase path command letters are relative, meaning the values are relative to the previously defined coordinates.

Uppercase values are absolute, relative to the upper left hand corner of the svg coordinate system.

Personally, while relative positioning can be useful, I favor absolute because I find it easier to reason about.

Here is an example where the numeric values are the same, but the behavior is different as a result of absolute and relative positioning:

```css
svg {
  overflow: visible
}

path {
  stroke: black;
  fill: none;
}

div {
  width: 150px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>relative</p>
  <svg>
    <path d="m 0 0 l 90 30 10 10 0 40" />
  </svg>
</div>

<div>
  <p>absolute</p>
  <svg>
    <path d="M 0 0 L 90 30 10 10 0 40" />
  </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Note that an initial "m" is always treated as an "M"

Comment: yes @MichaelMullany since it has nothing to be relative to

Comment: While the answer is technically correct it doesn't clarify the commands 's', 'c' & 'q' and their parameters. I don't know the answer either.

Comment: it only occurred to me to describe the difference between upper and lower case commands, s, c and q are all for bezier curves and different ways of defining them, cubic, quadratic etc... - it's complex but the spec and MDN do a good job of explaining it... @VelusamyVelu